# npm audit fix --force created more issues

Tags: npm

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe) in WebStorm, so I  installed Node.js, copied the files in, and ran `npm install`.

I went from:

```
8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)
```

to:

```
119 vulnerabilities (1 low, 97 moderate, 17 high, 4 critical)
```

just after running `npm audit fix --force`.

Why?

Running `ncu -u` and `npm install` now gives me:

```
8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)
```

Is this something I need to worry about?

Comment: `--force` is rarely the right thing to do - it installs versions that may be incompatible with the ones you actually asked for. If you're just following a tutorial, are the vulnerabilities relevant _at all_?

Comment: It's probably worth reading e.g. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174 and reviewing the audit with that in mind.